# How to read .s file with GCC?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I have a question about reading .s file with GCC.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and GCC.

I want to make a MIPS assembler by reading .s file like this:

$./runfile assembly file

here, runfile is c/c++ 's out file and "assembly file" is .s file.

what i have to do for this ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  What is “c/c++ 's out file?”  If you want to write an assembler, read some literature about lexing and parsing techniques.

Comment: Sorry. I write them vaguely. I just want to write code about MIPS assembler in C/C++. (because it's homework.) And i have to read .s file and complile the .s file to binary file(.o file) by using C/C++ mips compiler

Comment: @Karo If you want to use GCC for MIPS to assemble the assembly (.s) file to an object file, then I don't see why you need your own assembler.  After all, GCC for MIPS does include an assembler.

Comment: On most distros, you don't even need a cross-compiler package if you have clang.  e.g. on Arch Linux, `clang -c -target mips` can assemble MIPS `.s` files.  So you don't need to install a MIPS cross-compiler and cross-assembler.  (Ubuntu's gcc-mips package should include gcc itself and cross-binutils in the same package, though, so if you want the GNU toolchain install that.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, gcc knows that a '*.s' file is assembly, so it can "compile" it to an object without any additional info with:

```
$(CXX) x.s -c
```

This create the file `x.o` from your assembly file.

If you want also to use preprocessor directives/macros, you can add `-xassembler-with-cpp`

```
$(CXX) -xassembler-with-cpp x.s -c
```

or the file extension must be an upper case `.S` which has the same effect with gcc.

`CXX` must be your mips cross gcc.